# Callbable statement JDBC performance issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

I have Java thread getting data over socket and storing in an Oracle database.

Java 1.6
Oracle 12c
Solaris 10

I am calling a stored procedure from Java. I am using JDBC callable statement to call stored procedure.

```
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
Integer id=0;
try {
    connection = dbPool.getConnection();

    callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call xyz(?, ?)}");
    callableStatement.setString(1, "abc");
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    callableStatement.execute();
    
    id=callableStatement.getInt(2);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new Exception(e);
} finally {
    closeAll(callableStatement, connection);
}
```

The stored procedure is called for each message to store in the database and I need to call it for each message.
When I ran this stored procedure from PL/SQL block then it's processing 35 messages per second but Java application is able to process only 7 messages per second because callable statement is taking close to 150 millisecond to complete.

My question is how can I improve performance of Java call to Oracle stored procedure?

Comment: The code above creates a new Connetion and a new CallableStatement. Is the actual code you are executing doing the same, creating a new Connection and new CallableStatement for each message?

Comment: Yes unfortunately .Connection i am taking from pool so no delay there.Callable statement is the issue.As i said earlier i am getting single message from the source and need to call stored procedure for each message.

Comment: If the same repeated procedure takes longer to call from Java than from PL/SQL then I would guess the extra time is spent in network overhead. Are your Java program and database far away from each other? The common solution to this problem is to use batching - submit multiple requests at once so that you don't have to wait for as much network lag.

Comment: Yes both are on different servers but on the same subnet.

Comment: Have you enabled the implicit statement cache? You should. Everyone should. Always.